# Swift - Request to REST Api - Not readable

Tags: swift, rest, api

I'm sending a request to an API, but it always responds with an error `Not readable http body`.

In message it returns:

> exception = "class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException";
>           httpCode = 400;
>           httpMessage = "Bad Request";
>   Could not read document: Unrecognized token 'product': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@430128e1; line: 1, column: 9]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'product': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@430128e1; line: 1, column: 9]

But product isn't boolean, but string.

Anyone know, what's wrong?

```
    let api_key = Data(klic.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    let parametry = ["product" : "STANDART"] as [String : Any]
    let headers = ["authorization" : "Basic \(api_key)", "content-type" : "application/json", "cache-control" : "no-cache"]
    Alamofire.request("https://stage.japostparcel.cz/api/v1/order/", method: .post, parameters: parametry, headers: headers).responseJSON { (response) in
        //print(NSString(data: (response.request?.url)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
        print(response)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base url ends with `order/` so you post something like `order/?product= STANDART`. I am pretty sure you need some kind of page ref in between and not `/?` something like

```
`order/order_page?product= STANDART`
```

So check the documentation